# Can I restrict file types in Plupload?

Tags: plupload

I want to prevent people from trying to upload certain file types using Plupload. The documentations filters (i.e. prevent people from selecting files in the file browser) but it is still easy to get round and Plupload will allow the attempted uploading of these files:

http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php#configuration

Of course, the server then says that it doesn't want files of that type, but only after the upload has completed.

Can I get Plupload to refuse to upload files of a certain type (or only upload files of given types)?

Comment: You can try and validate the file on the first chunk on the server? Do oyu use chunking. If its not supported by the browser it will do a big post there is nothing you can do about it. Validation on the server is important. You can return a JSON reply on chunk 0 saying to stop upload - the client will then hook into that and stop it if a user finds a way to bypass the filter method.

Comment: Yeah the server is checking file types, but I'd like to prevent the user from attempting in the first place.

Comment: There are 2 situations here. Prevent common user (design allot of JavaScript catches and friendly messages) or prevent an experienced user/hacker(this on the client is impossible- you need to revalidate on the server)

Comment: Yep I can write some extra JS handling code, looks like I'll have to. I was just trying to verify that this feature was missing from plupload.

Comment: Can you further explain, how it is "easy to get round" with Plupload's filters settings? I thought, this kind of safe "restriction".

Comment: @trejder This was two years ago! I can't exactly remember, sorry. I just spent a few minutes trying on an example page and I can't make it work. So perhaps this was fixed in the last 2 years.

Comment: @trejder I just looked at the repository. The 'File upload error' string appears (I think) in November 2012 and this question was asked in July 2012.

Comment: Thanks, Joe! Let's pass on this! Have a great weekend! :]

Answer (score 1):

On the process of the fileupload or fileadd for that matter you could check the extension of the filename:

```
var test='hellothere.jpg';
var ext = test.substr(-3);
```

Then alert the user of the invalid file.

**UPDATE**

Additional validation will be required on the server. 1st check client side, 2nd Post to your upload method on the server side and remember if you have renamed your files look in the "name" property of the form and not the postfilecollection for the new name of your file. If theres any error you can just send json response say:

```
    "{"respCode" : "500", "Msg" : "Failed"}
```

Comment: Some experienced users could still bypass the client script and dump data to the server directly. It is always important to re validate server side. Your answer is correct but I find it as bad practise. Could you try and expand a bit / or include a best practice explanation. It would make it the best answer candidate.

Comment: Yeah you right there. Additional validation will be required on the server. 1st check client side 2nd Post to your upload method on the server side and remember if you have renamed your files look in the "name" property of the form and not the postfilecollection for the new name of your file. If theres any error you can just send json response say: "{"respCode" : "500", "Msg" : "Failed"}"

Comment: I think you should read the comments above and udpate you answer. You stand a great chance in earning an accepted answer.